# Use Google Drive as the UI for Google Cloud storage

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-drive-realtime-api

Is it possible to separate the Drive data store from the UI and use Google Cloud Storage instead for enterprise performance and permissions management reasons?

Answer (score 3):

No. I believe Drive and Cloud Storage may have similar backends but they are very different products with very different use cases.

For example, Cloud Storage objects (files), once created, [become immutable](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#concepts). This would not work with Drive.

With the [Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/storage/index) though, you could build a Drive-like UI for your users.